# Resize UIBarButtonItem

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem

My logo image is 1024x1024 and obvs. I need to resize it to make sense in the Navigation bar. 
For both iOS 11 and 10 I've found solutions, but neither work and I can't work out why!

```
    var reportButton: UIButton
    reportButton = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    let reportButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    reportButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    reportButton.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "1024Icon.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        // Running iOS 11 OR NEWER
        reportButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    } else {
        reportButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 23, height: 30)
        reportButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 15, bottom: 15, right: 15)
    }
    let rtyButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: reportButton)
    appBar.navigationBar.leftBarButtonItems = [rtyButton]
```

FYI I'm using MDCAppBar as the App bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can recommend you to do and what I usually do in these cases is that you create a new image that is your desired size for your image and use that image for your custom `UIBarButtonItem` instead. It´s tricky with the sizes when you have large images.

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 11 navigation bar uses autolayout so you have to add constraints in order to resize your UIImageButton, for example if you want to add a 30x30 UIBarButtonItem on the right side:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let btn = UIButton(type: .custom);
    btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "your_image.png"), for: .normal);

    btn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30);
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(your_method(_:)), for: .touchUpInside);
    let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn);
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([item], animated: false);    

    item.customView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true;
    item.customView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true;
}
```

see this [link](https://skyebook.net/blog/2017/09/uibarbuttonitem-sizing-in-ios-11/) for details